# Following the previous question: Existence of the natural density ...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Following the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848644/existence-of-the-natural-density-of-the-strictly-increasing-sequence-of-positive):

Let $A=\{a_n\}$ is a strictly-increasing sequence of positive integer. The natural density of this sequence is defined by $\delta(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{A(n)}{n}$ whenever the limit exists and where $A(n)$ is the number of elements of $A$ not exceeding $n$. Let $\delta(A)$ doesn't exists and $S$ is the set of all limit point the set $\{\frac{A(n)}{n}\ :\ n\in \mathbb{N} \}$. Is it true $|S|<\infty$? why?

Comment: What does $|S|$ mean?

Comment: @bof cardinal of the set $S$

Comment: Is it possible for $S$ to be a finite set? Intuitively I'd expect $S$ to be an interval. Surely $S=[0,1]$ is possible.

Comment: No, consider $A=\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, \cdots\}$, then $S=\{1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{7}, \cdots\}$, which has infinite many elements in $Q$, since we have infinite primes in $A$.

Comment: @XianjinYang an element is in $S$ if only if its limit point of  $\{\frac{A(n)}{n}\ :\ n\in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: @bof for any element in $c\in S$ must be there is a subsequence of $A$ :$a_{\alpha_{n}}$ such that its ratios converge to $c$, that's why I can't think that $S$ has infinite elements

Comment: @Deliasaghi The elements in $\{\frac{A(n)}{n}: n\in N\}$ is also limit points of itself. So, $\{1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{5}, \cdots\} \subset S$. It is still correct.

Comment: Let $r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots$ be any sequence of points strictly between $0$ and $1$. By using a variant of the trick used in the previous question, we can arrange for all the $r_i$ be limit points. In particular, let $r_1,r_2,\dots$ be an enumeration of the rationals. In that case, every real number between $0$ and $1$ is a limit point.

Comment: @XianjinYangIn what's your definition of "limit point"?

Comment: @XianjinYang If $A=\{1,3,5,7,\dots\}$ then $S=\{\frac12\}.$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm too lazy to write down the details, but isn't it trivial that the set of limit points is either a single point or a closed interval?

Comment: @Deliasaghi if the $s$ is a limit point of $S$, we can find a sequence in $S$ such that the sequence is convergent to $s$. Is this the correct definition for this situation?

Comment: @AndréNicolas we have one origin sequence $A$! how you use the trick for showing that $r_i$ is limit point?

Comment: @bof why? For $n=5$, $A(5)=3$, so, $\frac{3}{5} \in \{\frac{A(n)}{n}: n\in N\}$.

Comment: @bof: Probably you are right, we are getting from $a$ to $b$ and back in ever smaller steps.

Comment: @XianjinYang you must be find a sequence in $S-\{s\}$ not $S$

Comment: @Deliasaghi: We get close to $r_1$, then we get close to $r_1$ and to $r_2$, then we get close to $r_3$ then $r_1$ and $r_2$, then we get close to $r_4$ then $r_1$ then $r_2$ then $r_3$, and so on. But probably bof's observation works, which would simplify things.

Comment: @Deliasaghi I see, you are right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but there is a sequence $A$ such that $S=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Deliasaghi: I have "favourited" your question and will write something when I have time and if there is no answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think there is a sequence such that the set of accumulation points of the sequence $\frac{A(n)}{n}$ is $\{0,1\}$. Oh sure it is easy to make $0$ and $1$ accumulation points. But then every number between $0$ and $1$ is an accumulation point. The remark is due to @bof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$

**Lemma.** Given $n\in\mathbb N,\ A\subseteq[n],\ r\in\mathbb Q,\ 0\lt r\lt1,$ we can find $m\in\mathbb N$ and $B\subseteq[m]$ such that $m\gt n,\ B\cap[n]=A,$ and $\frac{|B|}m=r.$

**Proof.** Write $r=\frac pq$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb N.$

Choose an integer $k$ so that $k\gt\frac nq,\ k\ge\frac{|A|}p,$ and $k\ge\frac{n-|A|}{q-p}.$

Let $m=kq\gt n.$ Since $|A|\le kp\le|A|+m-n,$ there is a set $B\subseteq[m]$ such that $|B|=kp$ and $B\cap[n]=A.$ Of course $\frac{|B|}m=\frac{kp}{kq}=r.$

**Theorem.** There is a set $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ such that, for every number $r\in\mathbb Q\cap(0,1),$ the equality $$\frac{|A\cap[n]|}n=r$$ holds for infinitely many $n.$ (Therefore, every real number in $[0,1]$ is a limit point of the sequence $\frac{|A\cap[1]|}1,\frac{|A\cap[2]|}2,\frac{|A\cap[3]|}3,\dots,\frac{|A\cap[n]|}n,\dots.$)

**Proof.** Let $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k,\dots$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$ in which each element of $\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$ is repeated infinitely often. By repeated application of the lemma, we can construct a strictly increasing sequence $n_1\lt n_2\lt\cdots\lt n_k\lt\cdots$ in of natural numbers and a set $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ such that $$\frac{|A\cap[n_k]|}{n_k}=r_k$$ for every $k.$

Comment: Using your result, I can conclude that there is a strictly-increasing sequence of positive integer $A=(a_n)$ such that for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is $k$ consecutive numbers in $A$ and also there is two elements in $A$ with a gap of more than $k$. Is it true?

Comment: @Deliasaghi You don't need "my" result for that. How about letting $A$ be the set of numbers with an odd number of digits (in base ten), i.e., $A=\{1,2,\dots,9,100,101,\dots,999,10001.\dots\}$?

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer,